# Is there a CalDav client with email alert support on Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, calendar

Assume I had an Ubuntu Server with a CalDav server (in my case this is ownCloud 3), but the server didn't allow sending of calendar events by email to me. I'm looking to install a CalDav client, on the same server (must be command line driven), which I can subscribe to the CalDav server (on the same server), which will send out email alerts to me on events I put in there.

Any client as such available?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need caldav server to send emails of calendar-events? Theoretically radical, baikal can do it. But I think best way is to use Google-calendar (they have caldav support) & IFTTT. http://ifttt.com. First sync your owncloud calendar with google, then use email twitter, pushover or whatever notification you want with IFTTT.

Comment: You might want to check [khal](http://lostpackets.de/khal/) a brilliant CalDAV client for the command line, which you can then script with a cronjob to send you alerts.