# How do I enable a CalDAV server (in an OwnCloud installation) to send email reminders for events?

Tags: 12.10, server, lubuntu, evolution, calendar

I have a Lubuntu 12.10 server set up in VMWare VirtualBox with an OwnCloud 4.5.6 installation. One of OwnCloud's functions is as a CalDAV server. OwnCloud's web front-end doesn't yet have an interface for adding or editing event reminders. However, it does record settings for event reminders made by other clients -- Evolution, for example, can see reminder settings recorded in events that I imported into OwnCloud from a Google Calendar. However, email reminders for events in OwnCloud, even though the reminder settings are saved with the events, are not being served -- the CalDAV server hasn't sent me any reminders for these events.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to set up the CalDAV server so that it will send email reminders that are included in events' settings. I've read elsewhere that CalDAV can do this, and that it's just that OwnCloud doesn't provide a GUI for it yet. Is that correct? What would I need to do to set that up?

Thank you! I'll be grateful for any guidance you can offer to me!

A note: This question is bit similar to the question at [Is there a CalDav client with email alert support on Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100599/is-there-a-caldav-client-with-email-alert-support-on-ubuntu-server), which is old and was never answered.

Comment: Owncloud doesn't have reminder feature.https://github.com/owncloud/apps/issues/34. To get email notification you have to sync owncloud calendar with google-calendar. Then you can [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) to send email-notification, twitter notification, pushover notification or whatever notification you want.

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud `doesn't have` reminder feature. Here is the related bug:

https://github.com/owncloud/apps/issues/34

To get email notification you have to sync owncloud calendar with google-calendar. Then you can use [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) to send email-notification, twitter notification, pushover notification or whatever notification you want.